# Making ItemsSource treat a collection as a single item, rather than iterating over it?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, treeview, itemssource

I have a `TreeView` showing an object's properties. One of the properties is a large byte array.

TreeView's `ItemsSource` obviously treats this as a collection of child nodes, but what I actually want is ONE child node showing the entire array that can still be expanded/collapsed.

eg currently

```
- MyObject
    Prop1
    Prop2
  - PropWithBytes
      1
      2
      3
      etc
```

What I want:

```
- MyObject
    Prop1
    Prop2
  - PropWithBytes
      1, 2, 3  etc
```

Is there any way to tell the Tree to treat the collection as a single node?

If I didn't want the actual data to still be a separate node I could easily write a `DataTemplate` (as opposed `HierarchicalDataTemplate`) to to display it in place. I can also use a `DataTemplate` that uses an `Expander` instead to hide the data which works fine, but looks ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - try to use ValueConverter which will check if passed value is byte array or not (in case of byte array - returns it's string representation).

```
public class ByteArrayValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is IEnumerable<byte>)
            return string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<byte>)value);
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be perfect were it not for the fact that I still need access to the param as a byte[] within the child template (so I can wrap the data if it's too wide). I guess I could write another converter to convert it back again but that feels pretty yuck.

Comment: Have marked as answer because you inspired the actual solution - use a converter to wrap the array in another array of 1 item. Works great, thanks!